# Handling website access changes when using cookies

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies

If I have a site that uses cookies for authorisation, so when the user returns they don't have to login again.
If for some reason the site admin cancel this users account what is the best way to check for this. I don't want to have to hit the database every time the user visits a page to make sure their account is still live.
So how should I handle this situation?

Comment: Why don't you want to hit the database every time? Could you perhaps hit something like a memcached server?

Comment: Surely hitting the db everytime for a system that could have maybe 100,000 users online would begin to strain the db server?

Answer (score 0):

Several options.  Set a **shorter expiration** on the cookie so they'd have to get authenticated afresh sooner.

Another alternative is to have any **important action require** that they be authenticated against the database.  Thus you would only be hitting the database for more privileged actions that would more likely overlap with the high priority things you'd want a cancelled user be unable to do.